# "AudioClip " does not take a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#

on this line, which is line 10 it says "AudioClip" does not take a constructor that takes 0 arguments.  How to fix it? I know that AudioClip is a default class in Unity. What parameters shall I pass there or how to solve this issue?

```
AudioClip _clipRecord = new AudioClip()
int _sampleWindow = 128;
```

How to solve it?

```
public class MicInput : MonoBehaviour {

    public static float MicLoudness;

    private string _device;

    //mic initialization
    void InitMic(){
        if(_device == null) _device = Microphone.devices[0];
        _clipRecord = Microphone.Start(_device, true, 999, 44100);
    }

    void StopMicrophone()
    {
        Microphone.End(_device);
    }


    AudioClip _clipRecord = new AudioClip();
    int _sampleWindow = 128;

    //get data from microphone into audioclip
    float  LevelMax()
    {
        float levelMax = 0;
        float[] waveData = new float[_sampleWindow];
        int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null)-(_sampleWindow+1); // null means the first microphone
        if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
        _clipRecord.GetData(waveData, micPosition);
        // Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
        for (int i = 0; i < _sampleWindow; i++) {
            float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
            if (levelMax < wavePeak) {
                levelMax = wavePeak;
            }
        }
        return levelMax;
    }



    void Update()
    {
        // levelMax equals to the highest normalized value power 2, a small number because < 1
        // pass the value to a static var so we can access it from anywhere
        MicLoudness = LevelMax ();
    }

    bool _isInitialized;
    // start mic when scene starts
    void OnEnable()
    {
        InitMic();
        _isInitialized=true;
    }

    //stop mic when loading a new level or quit application
    void OnDisable()
    {
        StopMicrophone();
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        StopMicrophone();
    }


    // make sure the mic gets started & stopped when application gets focused
    void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus) {
        if (focus)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Focus");

            if(!_isInitialized){
                //Debug.Log("Init Mic");
                InitMic();
                _isInitialized=true;
            }
        }    
        if (!focus)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Pause");
            StopMicrophone();
            //Debug.Log("Stop Mic");
            _isInitialized=false;

        }
    }
}
```

on this line, which is line 10 it says "AudioClip " does not take a constructor that takes 0 arguments.  How to fix it?
----AudioClip _clipRecord = new AudioClip()----
       ---int _sampleWindow = 128;----

How to solve it?

Comment: Where is the code for `AudioClip` class ?

Comment: Either create a constructor in `AudioClip` that does take zero arguments, or pass the correct arguments to whatever constructor is currently defined.

Comment: I do not have a code for Audio Clip Class. Audio Clip is Unity's innner  class. I am not sure which parameters to pass there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AudioClip class add the following:

```
public AudioClip(){}
```

This issue arises because although you do initially get an empty ctor when you create a class, you lose that once you create a non-empty ctor so you MUST add the empty one if you wish to use it.

Comment: It says "Method should have a return type" and "Empty constructor is redundant"

Comment: Turns out AudioClip is a static class so instead of AudioClip _clipRecord = new AudioClip(); try AudioClip _clipRecord = AudioClip.Create();

Comment: " No overload for method. "Create" takes 0 arguments" - this is what it says

Comment: Ok, AudioClip _clipRecord = new AudioClip.Create("nameOfClip", lengthSamples, channels, frequency, true); Where nameOfClip is a string of what you want to name the clip, lengthSamples is an int stating number of sample frames, channels is an int for number of channels per frame(i believe that's like 2 would be stereo, 1 would be mono, etc...) frequency is an int for frequency, true is true because you're streaming from a mic

Answer (score 0):

In the new unity version just change `new AudioClip();`

with

```
AudioClip _clipRecord = null;
```

Hope it helps